# How do I remove file extensions from all files on Mac?

Tags: macos, script, file-management, rename

I have a bunch of files with arbitrary extensions OVER (i.e., *after*)
the old extensions; e.g.:

```
a10.lua.c76c8a36-6f80-4b5e-b6a4-ed7c6817ca2e
boneaxe.gif.e65e71e9-69e6-4d64-8648-1d6a9c8c7a1f
```

All of them are different. How do I automatically delete all of these extensions?

Background story: I deleted a bunch of things. I downloaded data recovery software. It found all the files for me, but left them in this messy format.

Comment: Please provide the syntax of your software added extension or the name of this software.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the software just added a 36-character GUID to the end of each file name. You can use this short bash script to remove them. Just `cd` to the folder with the files in a Terminal, and run the following:

```
for i in *; do
    j="$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's/\.........-....-....-....-............$//')"
    mv -- "$i" "$j"
done
```

Only files that have a 36-character GUID following a period, in the format you gave, will be modified.